# How can you download an app from the Software Center from a PC without Ubuntu to a USB

Tags: usb, software-center, gimp

I'm having a problem with networking device (Not Ubuntu's fault.) , so I am  using my moms Mac to copy an Ubuntu app to my USB device. When I try copy the file, the software center gives me a button asking me to install ubuntu to my mom's MAC!!! Sadly the answer was a **** no!!!

What I mean:

Wheres the server address for GIMP*****.DEB?!?!?!?!?!
Can you trick the site into thinking that you are in Ubuntu?!??

P.S Don't ask me why my networking stuff is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link you need in order to get the .deb contained in the repositories.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/